# OSM MapMarkerCircle, too large radius

Tags: openstreetmap, jmapviewer

When I tried to draw circle on JMapViewer with the following parameters:

Latitude:30.58654740901267
Longitude:31.504483034999993
radius : 100

I got the following gigantic circle
[image]

**What is the measurement unit used for this radius variable ?!!**

**code below**

```
MapMarkerCircle circle = new MapMarkerCircle(c, 100);
Color color = new Color(50, 0, 0,100);
circle.setBackColor(color);
mapViewer.addMapMarker(circle);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be something like... pixels.

It definitely wouldn't be a radius of a circle on the globe, because then you'd have to worry about spherical/cartographic projections.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is in degrees of latitude which means that the radius value of 1.0 degree corresponds to 111 km. I drew a circle on the map with the radius of 0.01, captured geo coordinates of the center of the circle and a point on the circumference and the distance came to .69 mile which is 1.11 km.

Hope this helps.

Wish the java doc for this product was more useful…